# How to create an element (div) using javascript event(onclick) on checkbox array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I'm creating an application which on selecting a value from a dropdown displays data from database using ajax. I want to create an html div element for each db record on clicking a checkbox. It works fine for 1 record but fails when I do it for multiple records using an array.

Here is my code. I'm using a function named  items which is triggered on click event of a checkbox:

```
function items() {
    var checkdetail = document.getElementsByName('values[]');
    for (var check in checkdetail) {
        if (checkdetail[check].checked == true) {
            var para = document.createElement("div");
            para.id = "head[]";
            para.style.width = "100%";
            para.style.height = "100px";
            para.style.border = "1px solid";

            var t = document.getElementById("table"), // This have to be the ID of your table, not the tag
                d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[2],
                element = d.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            element.appendChild(para);
        }

        if (checkdetail[check].checked == false) {
            var parent = document.getElementById("here");
            var child = document.getElementById("head[]");
            parent.removeChild(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance ..........

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that shows how you are trying to use this

Comment: is this function getting executed on success? and why are you assigning the same id for every element..

Comment: Actually the function is executed onclick() event on checkbox, i m assigning the id with array so i can remove them later on checkbox being unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a new row for each div or put all the divs in side the same row.

You are assigning the same string to ID for all divs. The ID is "head[]" and its added to every div - you're not assigning an array or an ID from an array you're making them all the same string value.

If you want to put them inside the same TR then you can move this code outside the loop.

```
var t = document.getElementById("table"),
d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[2],
element = d.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

and then you could put the "Head[]" ID on the TD instead so you know which cell to remove later.

If you actually want to separate a new row and cell for each DIV then you need to insert new TR / TD nodes into the table before inserting the DIV and give the DIV or TD a unique ID.

BTW if it really a Paragraph or text then using a

element may be a better choice in terms of styling with your existing CSS rather than forcing the style on the DIV through code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer,
Actually i m fetching records from db, so i want to create a new div for each record(row) using checkbox.
Can u tell me how can i add a new element or remove it for all the rows using checkbox, so that i check a checkbox a new element(div) should be inserted along the row, and if i uncheck the checkbox the element(div) should be removed.......
THanks for your Help.....

Comment: you can use http://api.jquery.com/after/ to append elements. and http://api.jquery.com/remove/ to remove them. Both links contain several working examles